# Обращение к элементам формы при их большом количестве

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Допустим, на форме есть ряд элементов: `label1`, `label2` и т.д. Пользователь вводит номер поля, которое он хочет изменить, и его значение. Как обратиться к полю по определённому номеру без использования `switch`?

Comment: Какой графический фреймворк вы используете?

Comment: @VladD использую CLR

Comment: А какой _графический_ фреймворк? (Под CLR вы имеете в виду, вероятно, C++/CLI.)

Comment: @VladD Windows Forms

Comment: Ага, Windows Forms.

Comment: А как Вы это планировали делать через switch?

Comment: @alexolut `switch (value) {case 1: label1.text=val; case 2: label2.text=val;}` и т.д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам разобрался.
Основная проблема заключалась в том, что нельзя добавить метки в обычный массив типа `Label^`, да и в вектор тоже. Но можно сделать так:

```
array <Label^>^ labels={label1,label2,...};
```

После этого можно обращаться к меткам следующим образом:

```
labels[i]->Visible=0;
```

И, соответственно, бегать по ним циклом.

Answer (score 1):

У контейнера (форма, панель и т.п), содержащего метки (label) есть свойство [Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1), возвращающее коллекцию дочерних элементов управления. Сделайте по этому набору цикл типа `foreach` и сможете получить доступ к каждой метке по очереди.

Если нужно получить конкретную метку по номеру, более правильным будет создать массив (или даже словарь `int`->`Label`), заполнить его один раз указанными метками, а потом уже получать доступ по индексу.

Есть и ещё вариант: использовать [`ControlCollection::Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) по списку, который вернет упомянутое выше свойство `Controls` и прямо использовать имя `label1`, `label2` и т.д. В общем, вариантов достаточно много.